# How to call keys as method calls on hashes in ruby without OpenStruct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to allow to call:

```
x = { 'lol': 2 }
```

using methods:

```
x['lol]
```

and

```
x.lol
```

They should both return `2`. I should be able to call any key in that hash which means I don't want to manually write a method for each key. I want to do this without `OpenStruct`.

Comment: `x = {'lol' => 2, lol: 4}` is a valid Hash. What would `x.lol` return?

Comment: I want x.lol to also return 2, as in, the object can access the keys as using square brackets and as a method call.

Comment: Maybe you missed my point. Your example is `x = {lol: 2}` where `:lol` is a Symbol key. However in my example `x` has a Symbol key `:lol` and a String key `'lol'` accessible by square brackets `x[:lol] #=> 4` and `x['lol'] #=> 2` so which key should `x.lol` return the value for? **Sidenote** your example is missing a closing quote and even if it  were there `x['lol'] #=> nil` because `{'lol': 2} == {lol: 2}`

Comment: As a further example `x = {String => 27}` is also a valid Hash. How would you envision calling this as a method?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, the way I am getting this object from parsing it, it will always be in a string format. That is, it will always be `x = {'lol' => 2 }`, never a symbol. I hope that clarifies things.

Comment: "That is, it will always be `x = {'lol' => 2 }`, never a symbol" – But that does not match up with your question. In your question, the key is a `Symbol`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, all keys will be Strings, which avoids any ambiguity between hash keys.

In its simplest form, you could build a class to handle this like so:

```
class HashMethodAccess 
  def initialize(h) 
    @_internal_hash = h 
    h.keys.each do |key| 
      define_singleton_method(key) { @_internal_hash[key] } 
    end 
  end 
  def [](val) 
    # alternatively public_send(val) if you would prefer NoMethodError
    # rather than nil
    # this would create a more unified interface but may cause some confusion
    @_internal_hash[val.to_s]  
  end 
end
```

usage

```
x = HashMethodAccess.new({'lol' => 2})
x.lol 
#=> 2 

# methods apply to each instance individually  
y = HashMethodAccess.new({}) 
y.lol 
#=> NoMethodError
```

**BEWARE**
While this can create methods from the keys not all methods can be called as `x.method_name` (You could write rules to handle some of these cases but  that is beyond the scope of the question)

```
x = HashMethodAccess.new({'2lol' => 2, 'foo bar' => 27})
x.2lol 
#=> SyntaxError 
x.public_send("2lol") 
#=> 2
x.foo bar 
#=> NameError 
bar = 12 
x.foo bar 
#=> NoMethodError (undefined method `foo'
x.send("foo bar") 
#=> 27
```

Comment: This would require me to instantiate a `HashMethodAccess` object. What if I simply want to do something like `HashMethodAccess.get_data(object)` and make it return an object that I can utilize the keys as method calls?

Comment: @yolo please explain the difference between `HashMethodAccess.new` and `HashMethodAccess.get_data`? Either way it needs to return an object that responds to your methods. Hash natively will not do this and I would never recommend monkey patching a core class.

Comment: @yolo is you are looking for a high functioning library you could look at [`hashie`](https://github.com/hashie/hashie) but given you didn't want to use `OpenStruct` I wasn't really sure where you wanted to go with this.

Comment: yes I can't use it because I am trying to avoid those libraries. Trying to do it using YAML library or anything manual.

Comment: Ah okay. One more question, I tried your method and it works for method calls. But the object that is returned cannot handle for square brackets. That is, `x['lol']` does not work

Comment: Hi, another question. I am trying to do this. I do `x.lol.first.yolo` but whenever I do `.first` or `.last`, it errors out when I try to call the next few after. That is, for the given statement, I am not able to get what `.yolo` is as I already used `.first`. How do I get around this?